# Retrieve a native connection from hikari-cp connection pool

Tags: postgresql, hikaricp

Can I retrieve a native connection from a `hikari-cp` connection pool or can I cast the proxy connection that it lends to a postgres connection?

I need to get a database connection from there and pass it to `CopyManager`. If yes, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `unwrap()` API.

```
PgConnection pc = conn.unwrap(PgConnection.class);
```

**EDIT:** Be careful, do *not* call `close()` on the unwrapped `Connection` instance, because `HikariCP` will not be able to track it properly.